# How to get TAG name which was passed in command line in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am running test cases using **robot --include smoke /**

I need smoke tag which was passed in command line argument in test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current tags are available in the Test level through the built-in variable `${TEST TAGS}`; you can iterate over its members to see what the case has:

```
FOR    ${tag}    IN    @{TEST TAGS}
    Log    tag: ${tag}
END
```

Yet that will give you all tags a case has assigned; so in your case it will return "smoke", but will also return "sanity", "feature" and all others it might have.

There's no exposed user-level variable/keyword to get what exactly were the tags set for the current execution; using the [RF API](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) you may be able to get a reference to the current execution context and access such property (if it's present).

Comment: To make it clear, your solution is not the right answer for the question. As you explained, it will log all tags for the current test case.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the OPTIONS built-in variable.

Example:

```
EDGE-T900 - Test tags
    [Tags]    CB1  CB2  CB3  CB4   CB5
    Log To Console   running test EDGE-T900 - Test tags
    run keyword if    'CB1' in @{TEST TAGS}   Log To Console    run because CB1 is on the tag list
    Log To Console    @{OPTIONS.include}
    run keyword if    'CB5' in @{OPTIONS.include}  Log To Console    run because CB5 is passed
    run keyword if    'CB2' in @{OPTIONS.include}  Log To Console    run because CB2 is passed
```

The OPTION variable includes all data passed by the command line, source documentation:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables

You can test it with:

```
 python3 -m robot "$@" -i CB5 -d results tests
 python3 -m robot "$@" -i CB2 -d results tests
 python3 -m robot "$@" -i CB1 -d results tests
```

And check the output...